# Propulsion force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, propulsion

My physics instructor gave us a general problem

> A box is sitting motionless on a rough, horizontal patch of ground. You give it a good kick, so that it slides to the right with an initial speed of 4.5 m/s. The box slows and eventually comes to a stop after traveling 14m. As the box nears the end of its motion, but while it is still moving, what forces are acting on the box?

and gave us these choices

> 1. normal force, weight force, friction force
> 2. weight force, normal force, propulsion force (the force that keeps it moving forward)
> 3. friction force, weight force, tension force
> 4. normal force, weight force, propulsion force (the force that keeps it moving forward), friction force
> 5. friction force, normal force, apparent weight force

He never explained what the propulsion forces are, that is why I am asking the question here. does the propulsion force apply in the above example?

Answer (score 2):

The propulsion force is a force that moves the body. So me "pushing" on the box is an example, or the canonical example of a rocket taking off.  Note that in your example, you "let go" of the box; this should answer your question.

Comment: The reason that this answer appears here is that the idea that a force is required to keep an object in motion is a common misconception. In fact, this is what aristotle thought. You can read this first paragraph of [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia#Early_understanding_of_motion) explaining what the old theory was. This question preys on people with that misconception.